# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline : conditionnal multiplication

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing a query on a mongoDB database that monitors some AWS Batch activity, but unfortunately the types of the field `updated_at` are not consistent.   ​

If the Field `status` is `submitted`, the type is `datetime.datetime` (ex : `2022-01-17T15:13:34.929+00:00`), if the `status` is `succeeded` the type is `time.time` (ex : `1642434736`, number of **seconds** since 1st January 1970).

As I cannot convert an `int` number to a date directly (I would need a double or another type) [[source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#:%7E:text=The%20following%20table%20lists%20the%20input%20types%20that%20can%20be%20converted%20to%20a%20date%3A)], I need to convert the Date to a number, here's how I did it :

```
db.topic_scorings.aggregate([   
    ​{
       ​$addFields: {
           ​timeSeconds: {
               ​$convert: {
                   ​input: "updated_at",
                   ​to: "double",
                   ​onNull: "$updated_at",
                   ​onError: "$updated_at"
               ​}
           ​}
       ​}
   ​}
])
```

But the issue is that the documents with type `int` keep the same value (number of **seconds** from epoch, just converted to type `double`), and the documents with type `datetime.datetime` are converted to type double, as the number of **milliseconds** since the 1st January 1970.
So my question is :

- How can I multiply the `updated_at` Field based on the value of the `status` Field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?
it converts the number to date
the multiple 1000 was to convert seconds to milliseconds

```
db.topic_scorings.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {
             status: 1,
             newDateField:
               {
                 //$cond: [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "submitted" ] }, "$updated_at", { $convert : { input: "$updated_at", to: "long" } } ]
                   //$cond: [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "submitted" ] }, "$updated_at", { $toDate : { $convert : { input: "$updated_at", to: "long" } } }]
                   $cond: [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$status", "submitted" ] }, 
                        "$updated_at", 
                        { $toDate : { $multiply : [ {$convert : { input: "$updated_at", to: "long" } }, 1000 ] } }
                   ]
               }
           }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much !

Comment: Glad that worked :)